# WooCommerce: Remove loop only on specific archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wcvendors

I want to remove the product loop from a specific product archive.
In my case it's an archive of a product vendor (WC Vendors plugin).
It seems to be a normal product archive. But I could check if it's a vendor archive with the following code:

```
$vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
$vendor_id   = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_id( $vendor_shop );

if ( $vendor_id) :
```

I've checked the template `archive-product.php`.  The loop is a function `woocommerce_product_loop()`. But how can I deactivate this function on that specific archive?

For elements on an archive I could use an hook like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use that approach for the loop itself.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Is it from a specifik taxonomy, you want to remove the loop?

Comment: it's a bit more complicated because it's an archive of product vendors from the WC Vendors plugin. But I can figure out how to check if it's that archive. I just need a function to remove the loop after that